# Java 7 ECC keypair generation with keytool

Tags: java, cryptography, keytool, elliptic-curve, key-pair

Correct me if i am going wrong somewhere as i am new to crypto field.

I am using following commands to generate EC keypair in Java 7:

As per : [docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#Commands](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#Commands)

**keytool** -genkeypair -alias MyServerPair -keyalg EC -keysize 571 -sigalg SHA512withECDSA -keypass 123456 -validity 365 -storetype JKS -keystore MyServerStore -storepass 123456

After execution,

Keystore gets generated in the directory. After that i try to export cert with following command:

**keytool** -exportcert -alias MyServerPair -file MyServer.crt -storetype JKS -keystore MyServerStore -storepass 123456

After which MyServer.crt is generated.

But when i open MyServer.crt file and check certificate status i find, "This certificate has an invalid digital signature"

Also, in certificate details when i see public key value it show ECC (0 Bit).

Why is that so ? Where am i going wrong ? My guess is i am using wrong signature algo.

I am referring,[docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/gui4des/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC)

Some Screenshots are [here](http://s9.postimg.org/lz9jm12rj/Capture.png)

**EDIT:**

Its happening when i use binary field values like 571 as -keysize but if i use prime field values corresponding to binary field values like 521 its working fine without above mentioned problems.

**EDIT 2:**

Even with other -sigalg values and key size 571 and other binary values problems exists.

I guess prime field values are only to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use arbitrary key sizes with ECC, but you choose a elliptic curve on which you do your cryptographic operations. 521 with be mapped to the NIST P–521 curve, there is no mapping for the key size 571, so it will not work. The name keysize is wrong here it should better be curve name for ecc.